# Detect which elements were added to an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comparison, detection

I have 2 arrays :

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
arr2 = [1,2, 82, 167,3,79,4]
```

I want to implement a function that realize the following

```
new_elems(arr1, arr2)
#=> [82,167,79]
```

Is there a ruby function for this?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Array#- would answer to this question. What about the performances then ? Let's say I have a thousands elements array. Would Array#- have acceptable performances ?

Comment: Can the arrays contain duplicates?

Comment: _"Would Array#- have acceptable performances?"_ – what is acceptable?

Comment: If you want to ask another question - just do it.